# How can I stop Fluent NHibernate automapping from creating foreign keys across the database?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I am using latest version of Fluent NHibernate automapping. Is there any convention or property I can set to stop creating the foreign key constraints across all the tables? I have nearly 200 classes, So I cannot go to each individual class and property name and set

```
 ForeignKeyConstraintNames("none", "none")
```

How can we add ForeignKeyConstraintNames("none", "none") in Automapping? I don't want to hardcode the table name or column name. I would like to have the AutoMapping create all the mappings without foreign keys. Basicall don't create any foreign keys across the database. How can we do this?
There is similar [POST HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503679/how-can-i-stop-fluent-nhibernate-from-creating-foreign-keys/16661237#16661237) but the answer was not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple convention

```
public class NoForeignKeys : IReferenceConvention, IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.ForeignKey("none");
    }

    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.ForeignKey("none");
    }
}

// use it
AutoMap.AssemblyOf().Conventions
    .FromAssembly() or .Add(typeof(NoForeignKeys))
```